# Trouble understanding the type of sequence [Just, Just]

Tags: haskell

I'm confused as to why I got this in GHCi

```
:t sequence [Just,Just]
sequence [Just, Just] :: a -> [Maybe a]
```

To elaborate, I can understand `sequence [Just 1, Just 2] :: Num a => Maybe [a]` because when looking at the type of sequence

```
sequence :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => t (m a) -> m (t a)
```

it is clear that this function takes a collection of monadic values and return a single monadic value of the collection. Thus, when we call `sequence [Just 1, Just 2]` we should get back a `Just` of `[1,2]`. Following that train of thoughts, shouldn't `sequence [Just, Just]` return a single `Just`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The second `sequence` works in a different monad.

For the first:

```
sequence [Just 1, Just 2]
```

we have that `Just 1 :: Maybe a` and this is a value in the `Maybe` monad. Concretely, the type `[Maybe a]` is matched against `t (m b)` as required by sequence, and we get `t ~ []`, `m ~ Maybe`, `b ~ a` -- hence the `Maybe` monad.

For the second:

```
sequence [Just, Just]
```

we have that `Just :: a -> Maybe a`. Which monad is this in? Now the type `[a -> Maybe a]` is matched against `t (m b)`, and we get `t ~ []`, `m ~ (->) a`, `b ~ Maybe a` -- hence we are now working in the `(->) a` monad, and no longer in the `Maybe` one.

In this `(->) a` monad, which is isomorphic to the `Reader a` monad, we have e.g.

```
sequence [f, g, h] = \x -> [f x, g x, h x]
```

Indeed, a computation with the `(->) a` monad is a computation "reading an implicit argument of type `a`". The `sequence` function simply turns a list of such computations (`[(->) a b]`, i.e. `[a -> b]`) into a single computation that reads the implicit argument just once, and produces a list with all the results
(`(->) a [b]`, i.e. `a -> [b]`).